# lxml - difficulty parsing stackexchange rss feed

Tags: python, rss, xml-parsing, lxml

Hia

I am having problems parsing an rss feed from stackexchange in python.
When I try to get the summary nodes, an empty list is return

I have been trying to solve this, but can't get my head around.

Can anyone help out?
thanks
a

`In [3o]: import lxml.etree, urllib2`

```
In [31]: url_cooking = 'http://cooking.stackexchange.com/feeds' 

In [32]: cooking_content = urllib2.urlopen(url_cooking)

In [33]: cooking_parsed = lxml.etree.parse(cooking_content)

In [34]: cooking_texts = cooking_parsed.xpath('.//feed/entry/summary')

In [35]: cooking_texts
Out[35]: []
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at these two versions

```
import lxml.html, lxml.etree

url_cooking = 'http://cooking.stackexchange.com/feeds'

#lxml.etree version
data = lxml.etree.parse(url_cooking)
summary_nodes = data.xpath('.//feed/entry/summary')
print('Found ' + str(len(summary_nodes)) + ' summary nodes')

#lxml.html version
data = lxml.html.parse(url_cooking)
summary_nodes = data.xpath('.//feed/entry/summary')
print('Found ' + str(len(summary_nodes)) + ' summary nodes')
```

As you discovered, the second version returns no nodes, but the `lxml.html` version works fine.  The `etree` version is not working because it's expecting namespaces and the `html` version is working because it ignores namespaces.  Part way down http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html, it says "The HTML parser notably ignores namespaces and some other XMLisms."

Note when you print the root node of the etree version (`print(data.getroot())`), you get something like `<Element {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}feed at 0x22d1620>`.  That means it's a feed element with a namespace of `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`.  Here is a corrected version of the etree code.

```
import lxml.html, lxml.etree

url_cooking = 'http://cooking.stackexchange.com/feeds'

ns = 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
ns_map = {'ns': ns}

data = lxml.etree.parse(url_cooking)
summary_nodes = data.xpath('//ns:feed/ns:entry/ns:summary', namespaces=ns_map)
print('Found ' + str(len(summary_nodes)) + ' summary nodes')
```

Comment: `data.xpath('//ns:feed/ns:entry/ns:summary', namespaces={'ns': 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'})`

Comment: gah, no wonder!  Looks like the api renamed the `namespaces` keyword at some point.  Updating my sample with working code.

Comment: thank you so much gfortune. I will begin to check the root before heading to parse it.

Comment: I spent like 3 hours figuring this out! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 6):

The problem is namespaces.

Run this :

```
 cooking_parsed.getroot().tag
```

And you'll see that the element is namespaced as

```
{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}feed
```

Similarly if you navigate to one of the feed entries.

This means the right xpath in lxml is:

```
print cooking_parsed.xpath(
  "//a:feed/a:entry",
  namespaces={ 'a':'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' })
```

Comment: Somehow I suspect this answer was easier for you than it was for me. ;)  Sheepishly bumping your answer and feel free to point out any errors I made in mine.

Answer (score 1):

Try using BeautifulStoneSoup from the [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) import.
It might do the trick.